# Overflow doesnt work when logged in with Drupal?

Tags: css, drupal, scroll, overflow

I have a div with a width set at 2000px. The div directly "above" (cant think of the word) that div has a 300px width. Also on that 300px wide div i have overflow hidden and overflow-x scroll.

When i log out of my site the scroll works. When i log back in it doesnt. My cache is cleared. What could cause this?

Comment: Please post the html dom tree so that we can better help you

Comment: Its in Drupal so there are lots of divs be created. I will though

Comment: render the page and then "inspect it" with firebug or chrome debugger - you will have the generated html structure there

Comment: I did but its to much code and to confusing. See for yourself http://pastebin.com/dxkg5Kxt

Comment: what browser are you noticing this with?

Comment: Try to create a minimal sample in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a height to the pickme div and now it works. Dont know how or why that fixed it but it works so im not complaining. Thanks to those who tried to help.